# Preprocessing CSV data efficiently before or while parallel streaming

Tags: java, csv, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for an efficient way to preprocess CSV data before (or while) dumping it to a java stream.

Under normal circumstances I would do something like this to process the file:

```
File input = new File("helloworld.csv");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(input);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
br.lines().parallel().forEach(line -> {
    System.out.println(line);
});
```

However in this current case I need to preprocess the records before or while streaming them and each item in my collection could depend on the previous. Here is a simple example CSV file to demonstrate the issue:

```
species, breed, name
dog, lab, molly
, greyhound, stella
, beagle, stanley
cat, siamese, toby
, persian, fluffy
```

In my example CSV the species column is only populated when it changes from record to record. I know the simple answer would be to fix my CSV output but in this case that is not possible.

I am looking for a reasonable efficient way to process the records from CSV, copying the species value from the prior record if blank, and then passing to a parallel stream after preprocessing.

Downstream processing can take a long time so I ultimately need to process in parallel once preprocessing is complete. My CSV files can also be large so I would like to avoid loading the entire file into an object in memory first.

I was hoping there was some way to do something like the following **(warning bad pseudocode)**:

```
parallelStream.startProcessing

while read line {
    if (line.doesntHaveSpecies) {
        line.setSpecies
    }
    parallelStream.add(line)
}
```

My current solution is to process the entire file and "fix it" then stream it. Since the file can be large, it would be nice to start processing records immediately after they have been "fixed" and before the entire file has been processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encapsulate the state into a `Spliterator`.

```
private static Stream<String> getStream(BufferedReader br) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String>(
                                            100, Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.NONNULL) {
            String prev;
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
                try {
                    String next = br.readLine();
                    if(next==null) return false;
                    final int ix = next.indexOf(',');
                    if(ix==0) {
                        if(prev==null)
                            throw new IllegalStateException("first line without value");
                        next = prev+next;
                    }
                    else prev=ix<0? next: next.substring(0, ix);
                    action.accept(next);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                }
            }
        }, false);
}
```

which can be used as

```
try(Reader r = new FileReader(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r)) {

    getStream(br).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The `Spliterator` will always be traversed sequentially. If parallel processing is turned on, the Stream implementation will try to get new `Spliterator` instances for other threads by calling `trySplit`. Since we can’t offer an efficient strategy for that operation, we inherit the default from `AbstractSpliterator` which will do some array based buffering. This will always work correctly, but only pay off, if you have heavy computations in the subsequent stream pipeline. Otherwise, you may simply stay with sequential execution.

Comment: I thought I would take this question and answer over the weekend with a custom `Spliterator`, I guess not anymore :)

Comment: Will you see the same benefit for a time consuming operation that is not necessarily heavy computationally (such as hitting a REST endpoint)?

Comment: You may see a benefit, depending on the I/O operation and environment, but the Stream API uses a configuration tailored to computation, i.e. using a target concurrency matching the number of CPU cores, which might not be the best choice for a particular I/O operation.

Answer (score 1):

you can't start it with parallel stream because it has to be execute sequentially to get the species from previous line. So we could introduce some side-effect mapper:

```
final String[] species = new String[1];
final Function<String, String> speciesAppending = l -> {
    if (l.startsWith(",")) {
        return species[0] + l;
    } else {
        species[0] = l.substring(0, l.indexOf(','));
        return l;
    }
};

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(new File("helloworld.csv").toPath())) {
    stream.map(speciesAppending).parallel()... // TODO
}
```

Comment: So what's the best way to track/store the prior species to be referenced on subsequent calls to the mapper? I guess what I'm asking is where do you define species?

Comment: It's a simple String array, updated the answer to put it in the code.